# Is there any advantage of genetic algorithm (or programming) over Neural Networks?

Tags: neural-networks, comparison, genetic-algorithms, genetic-programming

I am planning to switch from neural networks to genetic algorithms (GA) and programming (GP).

One of the main hassles of working with neural networks is that it requires a large amount of training data. Another issue with neural networks is that they require powerful computers for training, which I cannot afford.

Can genetic programming relieve me of these hassles?

I'm particularly interested in the *protein structure prediction* problem.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please provide some clarity on the problem you want to solve. Explain your rationale for considering a GA or GP. Solutions based on GAs and GPs can be very time-consuming and may require a cluster of computers that are far more expensive than a retail GPU if you want to finish the problem quickly.

Comment: Could you give an example of a problem that you want to solve? Preferably one where you have rejected neural networks as too slow and data-hungry.

Comment: @NeilSlater, Protein structure prediction.

Comment: They are doing different things. NNs are usually used for classification tasks, whereas GAs are for optimising a configuration etc.

Comment: Did you research the use of GA or GP for protein structure prediction? If so, what did you learn? A good paper should compare its approach to some baseline or alternative approaches, which will likely include neural networks.

Comment: @BrianO'Donnell Just vote to close the post as "details details or clarity" or "needs more focus". You've been on this site for so long, you should already know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few advantages of genetic algorithms (GAs) over neural networks using gradient descent for solving optimisation problems:

- GAs don't require relationship between any objective function (fitness function) and learnable parameters to be differentiable.
- GAs can alter hyperparameters of a model structure. This is related to the first point, but worth mentioning because it allows a GA like [the NEAT algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroevolution_of_augmenting_topologies) to alter structure of neural networks on the fly.
- GAs can be used to optimise models where the relationship between the models' outputs and end results are unclear, but those end results can be assessed. This is a property shared with reinforcement learning.

Unfortunately, this extra flexibility comes at a cost. Compared to gradient-based algorithms, GAs are often inefficient and slow. When a problem requires a model with a large number of free parameters, then GAs become impractical.

Regarding a requirement for lots of data and compute time;

> Can genetic programming relieve me of these hassles?

Not usually. In some cases it might happen that a small non-differential model neatly encapsulates the problem and a GA or GP could find it. But for most hard problems where large neural networks have been applied, there are no known alternatives than gradient-based learning algorithms that require significant computation and lots of data.

You may still have alternatives for specific problems in practice. However researching a hard data-intense problem from scratch using a GA could well require orders of magnitude more compute resources than gradient-based methods.

> I am particularly interested in the protein structure prediction problem.

There might be a role for GA or GP algorithms in searching for solutions to this problem. However, trying to frame the entire search as GA or GP is not practical. Instead a GA might be useful to *direct* model creation and testing.

There's no avoiding the significant difficulties and compute costs for research into the issue. At least not without a theoretical breakthrough in the core science of understanding how protein structures are created at the atomic level.